# In Golang http client, why there is MaxConnsPerHost but no MaxConns

Tags: http, go, connection-pooling

1. I see in Go http package:

   MaxIdleConnsPerHost int

   But I do not see any MaxConns for the whole http client, why?
2. If I only limit MaxIdleConns (per the whole client) is it possible to have more than this limit of active connections? (I assume the answer is a simple yes, but is it only theorethical?)

From the docs:

```
// MaxIdleConnsPerHost, if non-zero, controls the maximum idle
// (keep-alive) connections to keep per-host. If zero,
// DefaultMaxIdleConnsPerHost is used.
MaxIdleConnsPerHost int



// MaxConnsPerHost optionally limits the total number of
// connections per host, including connections in the dialing,
// active, and idle states. On limit violation, dials will block.
//
// Zero means no limit.
MaxConnsPerHost int
```

Comment: What would a `MaxConns` do that you can't do easily by yourself?

Comment: I am not saying it is impossible to do this by myself, but for example, an app is sharing an http connection by multiple handlers that are retrieving data from different vendors. I do not want to overload the network of the machine. I can solve this in many other ways, but a simple parameter on the http client would be nice to have.

Comment: And the same question can be asked for MaxConnsPerHost I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not see any MaxConns for the whole http client, why?

Because there is none. If you do not want to make more than n concurrent requests with that client, just don't do it (If the client would limit, it would be a major pita to use).

> If I only limit MaxIdleConns (per the whole client) is it possible to have more than this limit of active connections?

Yes. `MaxIdlConns` limits idle connection not non-idle ones.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I asked why, I meant why there is one, not why I can not find it :-)

Comment: I think that having a limit per the whole client does makes sense, and there are probably some legit cases where you would want this limit to come from the client, and not coding this limit yourself. I guess the Go team do not agree :-)

Comment: I assume your answer to "I assume the answer is a simple yes, but is it only theorethical?" --  is a simple yes. And thanks again for your response.